# How do I use substring to find the correct part of line of numbers?

Tags: c++, substr

Working on an assignement where I need to implement the knowledge of substring, but I run into compile errors with it.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <string> 
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

 int main() {
     string K;
     cout << "Sisestage isikukood:\n ";
     getline(cin, K);
     /* Küsin kasutajalt isikukoodi*/
     std::string str2 = K.substr(1, 1);
     std::string str3 = K.substr(2, 2);
     std::string str4 = K.substr(4, 2);
     std::string str5 = K.substr(6, 2);
     cout << "Isikukoodi I andmed:\n ";
     if(std::string str2 == "1") {
         cout << " *mees\n";
     } else if(std::string str2 == "2") {
         cout << " *naine\n";
     } else if(std::string str2 == "3") {
         cout << " *mees\n";
     } else if(std::string str2 == "4") {
         cout << " *naine\n";
     } else if(std::string str2 == "5") {
         cout << " *mees\n";
     } else if(std::string str2 == "6") {
         cout << " *naine\n";
     }
     std::cout << "* sundis " << str3 << "." << str4 << ".";
     else if(std::string str2 == "2" || std::string str2 == "1") {
         cout << "18" << str5 << ;
     } else if(std::string str2 == "3" || std::string str2 == "4") {
         cout << "19" << str5 << ;
     } else if(std::string str2 == "5" || std::string str2 == "6") {
         cout << "20" << str5 << ;
     }


 } else { /*Tulemus,kui isikukuud on sisestatud valesti*/
     cout << " Sisestasite isikukoodi " << K << " nime valesti.Palun proovige uuesti.\n";
 }
 getch();
 return 0;
 }
```

```
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp: In function `int main()':
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:19: error: expected primary-expression before "str2"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:19: error: expected `)' before "str2"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:24: error: expected primary-expression before "str2"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:24: error: expected `)' before "str2"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:28: error: expected primary-expression before "str2"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:28: error: expected `)' before "str2"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:32: error: expected primary-expression before "str2"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:32: error: expected `)' before "str2"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:36: error: expected primary-expression before "str2"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:36: error: expected `)' before "str2"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:40: error: expected primary-expression before "str2"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:40: error: expected `)' before "str2"

C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:45: error: expected primary-expression before "else"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:45: error: expected `;' before "else"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:49: error: expected primary-expression before "else"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:49: error: expected `;' before "else"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:53: error: expected primary-expression before "else"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:53: error: expected `;' before "else"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp: At global scope:
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:59: error: expected unqualified-id before "else"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:59: error: expected `,' or `;' before "else"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:62: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:63: error: expected unqualified-id before "return"
C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:63: error: expected `,' or `;' before "return"

C:\programs\c\Untitled1.cpp:64: error: expected declaration before '}' token

Execution terminated
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues:

- You terminated main() too early, the extraneous brace is right before your `else` statement.
- You keep using `std::string str# == something`, when that syntax is incorrect. Try `str# == something` instead since they're `std::string`s anyway.

Comment: http://v2.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/ This is what I based my work on, am I positioning the substr wrong or K.substr is not written like that

Comment: @wutimbad no, never mind -- it seems you're doing it correctly. Ignore the last point. The other two are correct.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the extrenuous bracket, This code is rife with errors unfortunately.

to fix your code you want to take out the "std::string" from `std::string str2 == "1"' in your  conditions. You are reinitializing your values which is causing problems for the compiler.

Secondly consider a case statement as the compiler expects the next condition after an else if so

> std::cout << "* sundis " << str3 << "." << str4 << ".";

is also causing compile problem.

Another problem I found was that you have dangling "<<" so change
`cout << "18" << str5 << ;`
to 
`cout << "18" << str5 << endl;`

Lastly, you getch is not defined

hope this helps